# Crash when calling clear on an Empty Map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dictionary

I'm getting a strange crash when I try to interact with a map in this particular class. When I try to call clear() or even begin() on the map it crashes. I haven't added anything to map, at this point nothing has touched it at all.

Code in question:

```
spriteMap_.clear();
if (!spriteMap_.empty())
{
    SpriteMap::const_iterator end = spriteMap_.end();
    for (SpriteMap::const_iterator it = spriteMap_.begin(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        it->second->draw(screen);
    }
}
```

Even stranger is that this is not unique to the map but to any maps in this particular class. I have another map, that is also not being touched until here (I tested it with a clear call in this function).

When I use intelli-sense on the maps both show themselves with tons of values already in them and the empty() call returns false. Similarily, size() returns a non-zero result.

Info:
I'm compiling in Visual Studios 2010 and linking against SDL.

Any help is appreciate.

**Edit (more info):**

My header has this line:

`private:
    std::map spriteMap_;`

And the only code that is hit is the function I showed you. I have other code but the break point on the function is never hit (I don't call that function).

But here it is:

```
Sprite* SpriteManager::createSprite(std::string fileName)
{
   ...

   Sprite* newSprite = &Sprite(nextSpriteId_, this, image);
   nextSpriteId_++;
   spriteMap_[newSprite->id_] = newSprite;
   return newSprite;
}
```

### **Fixed:**

**Moral of the story is don't ever do something like this:**

```
ObjPtr* objPtr = &Obj();
```

Comment: It sounds more and more as if you are corrupting the `map` memory somewhere within the class. Try placing data breakpoints on its memory locations, as I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably corrupting the map´s memory somewhere within that class. Get the map memory address, and see what happens when you attach breakpoints to such locations.

**Edit:**

> Sprite* newSprite = &Sprite(nextSpriteId_, this, image);

Here you are taking a pointer to a temporary object; note that is not even legal C++ but a nasty MSVC language extension. Right after you take a pointer to it, the temporary `Sprite` object is destroyed and you are left with an invalid pointer. You then derreference that pointer to get the id -which works just by chance here-, and then add that invalid pointer to the map. That´s at least one of the problems, it may or may not be related to your crash, there may be more problems out there.

Comment: My header has this line:

<code>
    private:
    std::map<uint, Sprite*> spriteMap_;
</code>

And the only code that is hit is the function I showed you. I have other code but the break point on the function is never hit (I don't call that function).

But here it is:


   Sprite* SpriteManager::createSprite(std::string fileName)
   {
       ...

       Sprite* newSprite = &Sprite(nextSpriteId_, this, image);
       nextSpriteId_++;
       spriteMap_[newSprite->id_] = newSprite;
       return newSprite;
    }

Comment: @Ryan Badour: You should edit the question to include that information. You are taking a pointer to a temporary object (nasty VC++ extension), which may be the cause of your problems.

Comment: @RyanBadour: It seems you want to do `new Sprite(...)` instead.

Comment: As I said, that code isn't being hit. Even if it were, isn't new for references, ie const pointers?

Comment: @RyanBadour: You seem quite lost at C++, `new` is for pointers (generally dynamic memory, aka heap). References are not exactly 'const pointers' although its not technically that far from that. I will update my answer considering the new information.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll take some try to revise my code based on what you said.

Unfortunately, that isn't the problem. Incase my suspicions were wrong I commented out the body of the function and I still get the issue. Even more troublesome I'm now seeing unrelated objects having integers (not pointers) being initialized to a very large value, something like 35526646 or so.

Comment: @Ryan Badour: That as well could be caused by memory corruption within your program. However, integers within objects/functions are not guaranteed to be zero initialized.

Comment: I see that, when I looked online it showed that uninitialized variables are set to that in the debugger. How do I properly initialize the map? Because it's the same value the int had.

Comment: Found the problem:

It's exactly as you said, but I had done that terrible thing everywhere. Including to initialize the SpriteManager it self. So it wasn't properly created for some reason. Thank you.